# IntPtr to Int - C#

Tags: c#, int, intptr, uint

I have this code :

```
public uint StringsSize { get; set; }
byte[] buffer = new byte[(IntPtr) XSC.header.StringsSize];
```

returning the following error :

> "Cannot explicitly convert type 'intptr' to 'int'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Any real guidance on fixing this would be appreciated, it's troubled me on several occasions with this tool ..
Also, I apologize if this is a duplicated question, I was unable to find a simple fix/solution after several Google searches.

Comment: Why are you casting to an `IntPtr` in the first place?

Answer (score 4):

Convert the IntPtr to the int type like so:

```
var buffer = new byte[((IntPtr) XSC.header.StringsSize).ToInt64()];
```

Comment: I believe `ToInt32` will return the _address_ as an integer, which does not make sense to use as the size of an array

Comment: Per the docs, "Converts the value of this instance to a 32-bit signed integer."

Comment: Right, but an IntPtr represents a _memory address_, so it will return the address, not the value that the address references.  Also it will fail on a 64-bit system.

Comment: If the system type is relevant, mine is 64-bit. A point to note however, is that I'm looking for item locations(addresses) inside a file to be decoded.

Comment: Hmm... then I think the code in general won't work. IntPtr to a location from a file seems odd.

Comment: @WowSkiBowse I think you need to add a detailed explanation of your situation (source data, process, expected result) to your question.  Right now it's not clear what you expect the `IntPtr` to represent.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
int numInt = intPtrVar.ToInt32();
```